# Pause program after displaying ten characters

Tags: c, ascii, pause, typecasting-operator

I want to be able to do something like pause the program after displaying 10 characters of ASCII values and say Continue or something to resume.
I use Visual Studio 2017 if that of any use.

Comment: C'mon, read the documentation.

Comment: and why are you shouting?

Comment: @SouravGhosh: The OP had been quieted down ... ;-)

Answer (score 1):

```
char str[] = "This is my string of text that will be outputted. After every"
             " ten characters, this will be interrupted.\n";

size_t i;
for (i = 0; str[i] != '\0'; ++i) {
    putchar(str[i]);
    if (i % 10 == 0) {
        printf("Press any key to continue . . .\n");
        getchar();
    }
}
```

Comment: "*... and **say** Continue or something to resume*"???

Comment: @alk Done [15 chars]

Comment: *LOL* .........

Comment: @alk I am not sure what the OP meant

Comment: @stackptr OP probably wants it interactive with keyboard

Comment: @pras i see now what the OP was saying

Comment: @alk fixed, i think i understand the question now

Comment: Thought you were joking ..., weren't you? ;-) I didn't downvoted this, BTW.